# Finding free humidity data

Tags: meteorology, open-data, humidity

I am trying to find historical humidity levels (ideally in percentage format) across the globe divided by sub-country regions or more granular. 
The time granularity would be daily, but hourly would be preferred. I do not have a historical range preference as long as there's enough data for at least a year. 
Any open data source where I could find this information? NOAA station data seem to be limited to temperature/precipitation. 
Google searches return corporate solutions in the thousands of dollars, which are not an option.

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data may be helpful, and remember that you can compute humidity from temperature and dew point.

Comment: Are you looking for observations? For a Gridded Dataset? Can you go a bit more in detail?!